# Embed reaction role collector is not working

Tags: discord.js, embed

I'm running into this issue where the embed reaction role doesn't work. Can someone help me?
Its most likely just the collector bit.

```
let playingMessage = await queue.textChannel.send(playingEmbed)

      await playingMessage.react("⏭");
      await playingMessage.react("⏯");
      await playingMessage.react("");
      await playingMessage.react("");
      await playingMessage.react("");
      await playingMessage.react("");
      await playingMessage.react("⏹");

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === message.author.id;
      filter: ({reaction, user}) => user.id === message.author.id
    var collector = playingMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
      time: song.duration > 0 ? song.duration * 1000 : 600000
    });

    collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
      if (!queue) return;
      const member = playingMessage.guild.member(user);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: (node:94) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: playingMessage is not defined

Comment: could you edit and share some more of your code to see what you have before `let playingMessage = await queue.textChannel.send(playingEmbed)`

Answer (score 0):

last i checked in discord.js v13, the filter should be within the curly brackets, not outside of it.

so this line of code:

```
 var collector = playingMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
   time: song.duration > 0 ? song.duration * 1000 : 600000
 });
```

Should be:

```
var collector = playingMessage.createReactionCollector({ 
   filter, time: song.duration > 0 ? song.duration * 1000 : 600000 
});
```